# Use CSS3 transform to fit element perfectly

Tags: css, css-transforms, skew, webkit-perspective

I'm trying to fit a youtube video to a phone's display but I can't figure out the perfect values. There's always a corner that not fits.

```
    transform: rotate3d(-131,-46,54,-53deg) skew(-5deg) skewX(10.2deg) skewY(1.9deg) perspective(82px) rotateY(1deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1.1);
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jvtg2cLd/)

Without the #layer 's z-index, you can see clearly that the top left corner is not fits.

Comment: It looks somewhat fine for me here,

Comment: Looks good here too (Chrome Mac). Can you specify the browser you are having problems with?

Comment: sorry I wrote top right, but I meant top left!